# How to override RowPersisting method in DailyFieldReport in Acumatca

Tags: c#, overriding, customization, acumatica

How can I override the RowPersisting method to get rid of the date -> project start date comparison and exception?

```cs
public class DailyFieldReportEntry : PXGraph<DailyFieldReportEntry, DailyFieldReport>
{
    public virtual void _(Events.RowPersisting<DailyFieldReport> args)
    {
        var dailyFieldReport = args.Row;
        var project = ProjectDataProvider.GetProject(this, dailyFieldReport.ProjectId);
        if (dailyFieldReport.Date < project?.StartDate)
        {
            args.Cache.RaiseException<DailyFieldReport.date>(dailyFieldReport,
                DailyFieldReportMessages.DfrDateMustNotBeEarlierThenProjectStartDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a PXRowPersisting delegate in the event parameters.  This will prevent the base method from executing.  Like this..

```
public virtual void _(Events.RowPersisting<DailyFieldReport> args, PXRowPersisting baseMethod)
    {
        //don't invoke the base method, to prevent RaiseException            
    }
```